# How to specify that a constrained, generic type is a reference in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function for the specs library that joins over an arbitrary `Join`able (in this case `I`):

```
fn calculate_unequip<I: Join>(
    entities: &Read<EntitiesRes>,
    items: &I, // FIXME: need this to be a reference, somehow
    equipped: &mut WriteStorage<Equipped>,
    owner: Entity,
    item_entity: Entity,
    slot: EquipSlot,
) -> Vec<(Entity, Equipped, Item)>
where
    I::Type: IsItem,
{
    (entities, equipped, items)
        .join()
```

I've written similar functions before, but the problem here is I call the function on a value of type `I` twice in the same scope, so Rust thinks the value of type `I` is consumed. So I somehow need to indicate this is an immutable reference. But when I do this (as shown with the `&I`):

```
the method `join` exists for tuple `(&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &mut Storage<'_, Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Equipped>>>, &I)`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`&I: specs::Join`
which is required by `(&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &mut Storage<'_, Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Equipped>>>, &I): specs::Join`
`(&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &mut Storage<'_, Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Equipped>>>, &I): Iterator`
which is required by `(&specs::Read<'_, EntitiesRes>, &mut Storage<'_, Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<Equipped>>>, &I):
```

This makes sense - `I` is a `Join`, not `&I`, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Could you not specify `items: I` as before, and add a bound `I: Copy`?

Comment: @cdhowie It appears not, since these are data types implemented by a 3rd party library - and I don't think it makes sense for them to be `Copy` either, as they may be somewhat large storage data structures.

Comment: I thought that `I` was a reference? If so, copying it is trivial.

Comment: Oh right, was thinking about that in totally the wrong way - thanks @cdhowie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either add a bound `I: Copy` which would allow you to pass a shared reference, since they implement `Copy`, or using [Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) you could bound `&I` to be `Join`.

```rust
fn foo<I>(_: I)
where
    for<'a> &'a I: Join
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of HRTB's - that's great to know about. However, I'm still unsure of how I can simultaneously specify the constraint `I::Type: IsItem`, as this constraint requires we have already assumed `I: Join`, and specifying it at the same level in the where clause does not seem to pick that fact up.